# Creating a Todo List in Java

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

As i m a new programmer, i m interesting for the right aproach. I want to make a todo list, very simple at the beggining but with more features later.

I have this code:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    class AddtoList{
        public static void main (String[]args{
               Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
               String task = scanner.nextLine();
               ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>;
               myList.add(task);
```

Assuming that later i want to mark task as completed, or have different lists, priority etc. Is this a right approach or should i have to create a task Class, a createList class and then add the "object" task in an ArrayList ?
I know that the best way is to be easier to maintance, but until now i m deleting and writing classes all the time without be able to understand which is the best approach.

Comment: **TODO** or **TASK** or something equivalent to those are not related to Java programming.

Comment: @zlakad could you elaborate on what you mean by your comment? I don't understand at all.

Comment: @Stanislas how can I elaborate something so obvious - can you provide me some, *any*, example? TODO is something what you should implement later, or in community environment ASAP.... Nothing related to Java, class, object or arraylist...

Comment: @zlakad From my understanding, Angelbreath wants to create a simple application that holds a list with items that still need to be done (a.k.a. TODO-items). He's not trying to make a list that needs to be implemented later. I don't understand why you're saying that the functional-contents of a programming exercise are not related to programming. It's not obvious to me at all.

Comment: @Stanislas, O.K. my friend, why don't you just provide an answer? I admit I cannot... BTW, I stated it is not related to Java (and probably it is related to general algorithms)

Comment: It is tough to provide an answer, as this is really a matter of your taste, experience/expertise and abilities.  You are asking good questions, so keep doing that as you develop your program. You'll soon discover what works best for you. 

Comment: Yes you should make your task a class. If you write java you write a lot of classes.

Comment: @Stanislas sorry if i wanst very clear in my question. I want to make a very simple todo list, like "buy milk, buy cereal etc. I want my list be printed and have tasks as completed. I want very simple at the beginning. But when its done, i want to make it more complex. So i want from the begging to have the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a programming exercise, why not try everything you're thinking of?

Once you've finished, try adding in a new requirement, for example: priorities.
You'll notice that some approaches are more open to change than others.
Don't be afraid of doing some [Code refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring)!

You might benefit from looking into some [design patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do) and coding principles, like [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

It's very hard to present you with a single answer, simply because there are so many possible solutions, each with their own downsides.

Once you've tried your own hand at some implementations, you might also want to look up some examples on the internet as there are plenty. The Udacity course on [Java Programming Basics](https://eu.udacity.com/course/java-programming-basics--ud282) even has a step-by-step implementation of a TODO-list.

It's important to note that there rarely is a **wrong** approach, there are only **better** approaches.
Once you've finished, head over to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and see what the community thinks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Its a self learning exercise.Actually i ve done it but i m not satisfied of the code as things are not "exactly" as i want.  I m trying to make it better but somethings confuse me, as i m thinking that its not right approach for making more complex things later.